# How to schedule monthly Trial Balance Report in NetSuite

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to schedule monthly Trial Balance Report. For example, next 1 February 2023, I want to receive an email with the January 2023 Trial Balance report. Next 1 March 2023, I want to receive an email with the February 2023 Trial Balance report. Etc...

What is the configuration I have to set to do that?

Just setting the "End of" field to "Last Period" and creating the monthly schedule report (see screenshots)?

Any idea on how to do it?

[Schedule Report Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Xy4.png)

[Trial Balance Report Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdJSk.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question ,I hope you want to receive monthly trial balance report(one month data).
You need to choose the **Start Date** as **1st Feb, 2023**(Day before the chosen day of month) in **schedule configuration**.
And you can also add **Date Created** under **filters** section under the **trial balance report configuration** and choose it to **last month**.
I hope it will work.
Thanks,